# password change in mvc popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `@Html.Password("Password", ViewData["password"])` for displaying passwords in popup, the password is being displayed and I should be able to edit and update it. After  editing it, when I click save button the password is not being updated.

`ModelState.IsValid` is giving `False` and the method is being skipped.

this is my view

```
@Html.Password("Password", ViewData["password"])
```

controller

```
       [httppost]
       public actionresult edituser(sales.users saleUser)
       {
        sales.users objUser=new sales.users();
        sales objSaleModel=new Sales();

        if(modelstate.isvalid)
        {

          //the code to save the changes
        }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)

Comment: added the sample code, near modelstate.isvalid its returning false

Answer (score 0):

Model.IsInvalid due to various other aspects.

any element in the model might not be valid.

So check your model what validations you have put on fields.

Comment: in model the password field is chaging,thats causing the problem

Comment: Ok have you put any validation on this?
This is one of my code in running project

`code
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Index))]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[CustomStringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LengthValidationString", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Index))]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
`